# Keep colour stay on the map -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, raphael, jquery-effects, world-map

I'm studying how to make a World Map using JavaScript. I found this amazing example at http://backspace.com/mapapp/javascript_world/. However, I want the colour of each state stay after the click (But the rest will still be #efefef when the cursor is away if they weren't clicked). I'm new to JavaScript, and I wish I can solve this problem.

```
        // when cursor is over
        st[0].onmouseover = function () {
            current && map[current].animate({fill: "#efefef", stroke: "#666"}, 300);
            st.animate({fill: st.color, stroke: "#ccc"}, 300);
        };

        // when clicking
        var flag = true;
        st[0].onclick = function () {
            if(confirm("Have you been to " + state + "?" )) {
                st.animate({fill: st.color, stroke: "#ccc"}, 300);
                flag = false;
            }
        };

        // when cursor is away
        if(flag) {
        st[0].onmouseout = function () {
            st.animate({stroke: "#666",fill: "#efefef" }, 300);
        };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$animate` change the css of `st` element and set a `background-color`.
This way the background of the element will be persistent.

```
st.css({'background-color': <color-code>});
```

I hope this will helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. But I want to keep the colour persistent upon the click on each state.